# Laravel Excel - multiple sheets with custom view

Tags: php, excel, laravel-excel

I have been trying to export a multi sheet .xlsx spreadsheet using a custom view without any luck - the sheet ends up blank.

TransactionsExport.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Exports\Sheets\TransactionsByBillerSheet;
use App\Models\Biller;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class TransactionsExport implements WithMultipleSheets, FromView
{
    use Exportable;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];
        $billers = Biller::orderBy('name')->get();
        foreach ($billers as $biller) {
            $sheets[] = new TransactionsByBillerSheet($biller);
        }

        return $sheets;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('exports.transactions');
    }
}
```

TransactionsByBillerSheet.php -

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports\Sheets;

use App\Models\Biller;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class TransactionsByBillerSheet implements FromQuery, WithTitle

{
    private $biller;

    public function __construct(Biller $biller)
    {
        $this->biller = $biller;
    }

    /**
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function query()
    {
        return Transaction::whereBillerId($this->biller->id)->orderBy('date')->get();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function title(): string
    {
        return $this->biller->name;
    }
}
```

I am mainly trying to change the column names from A,B,C and also do some formatting of the result. Using the View would be ideal but I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish that while using the multi sheet functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: query() is supposed to return a query, remove ->get()

Comment: Tried both ways, no dice.. Wondering if it's because nothing is being passed to the view method? I recall the documentation being much more concise when I used this package years ago..